# How to downcast an array in Java?(Polymorphism)

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism, downcast

I currently have a `Supercar` class that extends a `Car` class, and want to downcast an array of `Car` class.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfbov.png):

```java
System.out.println("\nLab Task 6");
Car[] cars = new Car[10]; //object array
cars[0] = new SuperCar( model: "Lambo", cc: 8000, type: "Car", transmission: "Manual", powertrain: "Electric", maxSpeed: 300);
cars[1] = new SuperCar( model: "BMW", cc: 4500, type: "Car", transmission: "Manual", powertrain: "Electric", maxSpeed: 200);
Supercar superD = (SuperCar)cars[];
```

Is that any problem or error inside the code?

Comment: Does it compile without errors?

Comment: Please share your code instead of an image

Comment: @YCF_L i'm new to here, still learning to the basic of posting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: it would be beneficial, if you did not include a screenshot but pasted the code directly with highlighting. By this, we can directly provide edited code which directly relates to your code in the question.

The general idea you are trying to realize is called *widening* in terms of treating an instance of a subclass as an instance of its superclass and it's perfectly fine to do this. The reverse action would be called *narrowing*.
However, in terms of your code, you cannot cast an array of Objects to another Object, you would need to enter an index to access a car from your array, which you then cast to your specialized class SuperCar.

Something like this should work:

```
SuperCar superD = (SuperCar) cars[0];
```

Although you'll have to think of how to access all of the different cars in the array.

Comment: So it's mean if i want to do downcasting for the array part must create one by one to access the specific class?

Comment: @oscar I am really not sure what you are trying to achieve, since it was not clear form the initial question. If you want the whole array of cars, you can also cast the array via ```SuperCar[] superD = (SuperCar[]) cars;```

Comment: How do i call `SuperCar[] superD = (SuperCar[]) cars;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast array of objects to another object. You can try doing as below

```
     SuperCar d = (SuperCar) car[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize an array with its own type:

`Car[] cars = new Car[10];`

even though Car is a superclass, you can not downcast the cars array. For this reason, below code will throw `ClassCastException`

`SuperCar[] superD = (SuperCar[])cars;`

If you want to downcast the Car array, you have to initialize this array with subclass type:

`Car[] cars = new SuperCar[10];`

and you can downcast this array to SuperCar.

`SuperCar[] superD = (SuperCar[])cars;`